# About XSD Element is invalid ( XML Schema)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a question about XSD formatting. 
For examples , I have a XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <entry>
    <title>Examples</title>
    <id>1</id>
    <media:group>
      <media:thumbnail url="http://www.abc.com/image.jpg" />
      <trailer url="http://www.abc.com" />
      <info url="http://www.abc.com/xsd/info.jpg" />
      <media:description>1</media:description>
      <media:content name="video.mp4" type="video" duration="400" repeat="true"/>
    </media:group>
    <menu>
      <item uri="localhost:8080/xyzt" />
    </menu>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

And then, I use the website http://www.xmlforasp.net/codebank/system_xml_schema/buildschema/buildxmlschema.aspx for auto convert to XSD file( you can try it). However, when I use the website http://www.xmlforasp.net/schemavalidator.aspx for check XSD validator , at that time have a problem about XSD formatting 
Problem :

> Invalid 'name' attribute value 'media:group': 'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, at position 5 within the name, cannot be included in a name.'.

```
    <xsd:element name="entry">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" />
          <xsd:element name="media:group">             <!-- here -->
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
```

I do not understand ... Why the name of xsd:element can not include ":" character ???
If the above problem is Right , how can I fix it.

Please help me if you known that. 
Thank you very much !

Comment: It's helpful if you include the schema, because that's where the error is. Hang on, I'll fix it... done.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different validator. I don't know anything about this site, but from your evidence, they are parsing the XML using a non-namespace aware XML parser. That's a pretty bizarre thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The text before the ":" is called a `namespace`. e.g. in "media:group", the namespace is "media".

To define an element in a namespace, you can't just say it like `<xsd:element name="media:group">` as you'd expect.

Instead, you have to specify it as the `targetNamespace` for the whole schema, and then *all* elements defined in that schema will have that namespace.  Like this (the `qualified` part means that your XML needs to use the namespace, as your XML does with "media"):

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" ...>
  ...
  <xsd:element name="group">
```

You can also have a schema whose elements have no namespace, by [omitting](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#UndeclaredTNS) `targetNamespace`:

```
<xsd:schema ...>
  ...
  <xsd:element name="entry">
```

Note: to define elements in two namespaces, you need two schemas. Normally, you can combine schema by `importing` one into another. But there's a problem with your XML: the references to namespaces are cyclic in that `<entry>` contains `<media:group>`, which contains `<trailer>`.

**Sorry: I cannot solve this.** My best attempt used a third schema (defining `<trailer>`), but this crashes `xmllint`... Can anyone else solve it?